# Trying to split text from title

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to remove these from my output: I want these only `Wave Coffee Collection`

```
'\n\n\t\t3rd Wave Coffee Collection\n\t\t\t\t\n\t'
```

This is my code :

```
from scrapy.http import Request
import scrapy
class PushpaSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'
    start_urls = ['https://onepagelove.com/inspiration']
    

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//div[@class='thumb-image']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            absolute_url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(absolute_url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        title = response.xpath("//span[@class='review-name']//h1//text()").extract_first()
        


        yield{
            'title':title
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your resulting output:

```
result = '\n\n\t\t3rd Wave Coffee Collection\n\t\t\t\t\n\t'
```

Then you can easily achieve your desired output like this:

```
result = result.strip()
```